# вернуть индексированный массив без ключа laravel

Tags: php, массивы, laravel

Попробовал очень много от

```
$ids = Site::lists('id')
```

до

```
$ids = Site::pluck('id')->toArray()
```

и все они возвращают

```
[0] => 37 [1] => 41 [2] => 42 [3] => 43 [4] => 45 [5] => 46
```

а мне нужно получить

```
array(37,41,,42,43,45,46)
```

Comment: это одно и то же

Comment: Вопрос не в этом заключался одно и тоже или нет.

Answer (score 0):

Внимательно прочитайте документацию:
На самом деле массив в PHP - это упорядоченное отображение, которое устанавливает соответствие между **значением и ключом**. Этот тип оптимизирован в нескольких направлениях, поэтому вы можете использовать его как собственно массив, список (вектор), хэш-таблицу (являющуюся реализацией карты), словарь, коллекцию, стэк, очередь и, возможно, что-то еще. Так как значением массива может быть другой массив PHP, можно также создавать деревья и многомерные массивы([документация](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.array.php)).

Comment: Эту документацию я давно видел, а как оно относится к вопросу, я Вам вопрос о том есть ли возможность такая в Laravel получить сразу ныжный мне вид массива, а Вы мне о том какие бывают массивы в РНР, реально?

Comment: Внимательно почитайте свой вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Если ключи идут по порядку от 0 до n, то считается что массив индексирован без ключа.
И наоборот если у массива не указывать ключи, то php автоматически будет считать ключом index увеличивающийся от 0 до n.
Если вы выполните json_encode на такой массив,то получите значения через запятую.
Если вам нужна просто **строка** вида `array(37,41,42,43,45,46)` то можете использовать функцию implode():

```
echo "array(" . implode($ids, ',') . ")";
```

Но через dd(), print_r(), var_dump() и т.п. вы не сможете вывести массив без ключей, он их будет добавлять автоматом, даже если массив индексирован без ключей.